# JavaScript Multi Step Form Validation Bootstrap, Html, CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, codeigniter

I am trying to create a multistep form using JavaScript and div. I know how to create the form this way but the problem is I want the fields in each step to be validated before moving to the next. Example: If the user did not fill up a required field or have error in a field the box will be highlighted in red and they will not be bring to the next step until it is corrected. I know how to do validation but not able to stop the page. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Without any code and context we are not able to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the [constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Constraint_validation) to put validation onto your input element
2. Listen to when `onsubmit` gets triggered on the form element and [prevent the default behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). (it is only going to be triggered once the form is valid, not when it's invalid, so there is no need for javascript validation). **Don't** listen to `button or input[type="submit"]` click event that many developer makes a misshabit of using. The constraint validation messages don't kick in otherwise
3. Hide the form/section, and show the next step

```js
globalThis.onsubmit = evt => {
  evt.preventDefault()
  const submittedForm = new FormData(evt.srcElement)
  console.log([...submittedForm])
  evt.srcElement.hidden = true
  evt.srcElement.nextElementSibling.hidden = false
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input required placeholder="First name" name="given-name" autocomplete="given-name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<form hidden>
  <input required placeholder="Last name" name="family-name" autocomplete="family-name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```